# MongoDB: apply $filter stage only if a condition is met?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a data model that looks like this:

```
{
  "company": <company name>,
  ...,
  "subFields": [
    {
      ...,
      "division" <division name>
    },
    ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Given this data model, my mongoDB pipeline needs to just match documents whose `company` is in a list `all_companies`, and filter the contents of others whose company is in a list `special_companies`, each according to its own rule. So for example for `special company #1` we only want `subFields` elements whose `division` field has a specific value, thus the following filter must be applied:

```
{
  "$addFields": {
    "subFields": {
       "$filter": {
         "input": "$subFields",
         "as": "subFields",
         "cond": {"$eq": ["$$subFields.division", <division of special company #1>]}
       }
     }
  }
}
```

So in practice there should be a kind of if statement after the general `$match: {"company": {"$in": all_companies}}` stage.

```
if company == special company #1:
    then apply filter #1
if company == special company #2:
    then apply filter #2
...
else:
    just pass all the results of $match
```

How can this be accomplished using aggregation operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cond` part of `$filter` excepts `true` or `false` to be returned. Regardless of how complex the right-handside expression is. In your case you can use [$swtich](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/) to specify filtering conditions based on `company` value:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            "subFields": {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$subFields",
                    cond: {
                        $switch: {
                            branches: [
                                { case: { $eq: [ "$company", "company 1" ] }, then: { $eq: [ "$$this.division", "div 1" ] } },
                                { case: { $eq: [ "$company", "company 2" ] }, then: { $eq: [ "$$this.division", "div 2" ] } }
                            ],
                            default: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ttwRDVX6XgO)